# How to solve failed job batching in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, queue, job-batching

I made a job batching to insert csv into database.

Here is the method:

```
public function upload()
{
    if(request()->has('file')){
        $data = file(request()->file);
        
        // Chunking file
        $chunks = array_chunk($data,5);
       
        $batch = Bus::batch([])->dispatch();

        foreach($chunks as $chunk){
            
            $data = array_map('str_getcsv',$chunk);

            $batch->add(new BinlocCsvProcess($data));
        } 

        return $batch;
    }
    return 'please upload file';
}
```

And this is my Job class:

```
class BinlocCsvProcess implements ShouldQueue {

public $data;
/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($data)
{
    $this->data = $data;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    foreach($this->$data as $item){
        Binloc::create($item);
    } 
}
}
```

I don't know how to get the error why it doesn't work and I don't have any idea how to solve it.

Comment: can you specify what was the error>

Comment: I don't know how to get the error. when i run php artisan queue:work, all the process is fail

Comment: i got the error. ErrorException: Undefined variable: data in /binloc/app/Jobs/BinlocCsvProcess.php:36

Comment: Create a new job instance. from  class in constructorr

Comment: The problem was solved. In handle() method should be **$this->data as $item** , not   $this->$data as $item. Thank you @JEJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error appear because line `foreach($this->$data as $item)`. You should remove `$`, so your code should be like this `foreach($this->data as $item)`.